# what is wrong with the metrics arg in this code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

please look at this code

```
solver = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
model.compile(
optimizer=solver,
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=[
    metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(0.5),
    metrics.SpecificityAtSensitivity(0.5),
    metrics.Precision(),
    metrics.Accuracy(),
    metrics.AUC()
]
)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    rotation_range=270,
)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'DFU_Dataset/training',
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=8,
        class_mode='binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'DFU_Dataset/testing',
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=8,
        class_mode='binary')
```

up to here everything executes fine with no errors or warnings at all, now when i execute this next part :

```
model.fit(
    train_set,
    epochs=40,
    validation_split= 5.9,
    verbose=1
    )
```

i get : "ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible".

now when i completely remove the metrics arg like in here :

```
model.compile(
optimizer=solver,
loss='binary_crossentropy'
)
```

everything works fine and starts training.

can you please point out what am doing wrong and a way to fix it.

Comment: what is your model architecture or model building part of the code? or Can you show model.summary()

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan Janapati i added the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root-cause is shape mismatch between data and prediction. 
Last layer for the binary classification should have

```
Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

Based on the above model.summary(), currently you have 2 nodes in the output layer whereas some metrics are looking for single output.